# Find all foreign keys constraints in database referencing a certain primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key, foreign-key-relationship

I want to find all foreign keys in my database that reference to a primary key of a certain table.

For example, I have a column `A` in table `T` which is the primary key. Now I want to find in which tables column `A` is referenced in a foreign key constraint?

One simple way I've considered is to check the database diagram, but this only works if a database is very small. It's not a very good solution for a database that has more than 50 tables.

Any alternatives?

Comment: or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700303/sql-2008-foreign-key-constraints-in-the-information-schema-view (accepted answer covers the problem here I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [How to find foreign key dependencies in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925738/how-to-find-foreign-key-dependencies-in-sql-server)

You can sort on PK_Table and PK_Column to get what you want

Comment: Thanks for your answer,and i find other way :right click on a table and select view dependencies .

Answer (score 10):

On the last line, change [Primary Key Table] to your table name, change [Primary Key Column] to your column name, and execute this script on your database to get the foreign keys for the primary key.

```
SELECT FK.TABLE_NAME as Key_Table,CU.COLUMN_NAME as Foreignkey_Column,
       PK.TABLE_NAME as Primarykey_Table,
       PT.COLUMN_NAME as Primarykey_Column,
      C.CONSTRAINT_NAME as Constraint_Name 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS FK ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME =Fk.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK ON C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME=PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE CU ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT i1.TABLE_NAME, i2.COLUMN_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS i1
            INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE i2 ON i1.CONSTRAINT_NAME =i2.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
        WHERE i1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
    ) PT ON PT.TABLE_NAME = PK.TABLE_NAME
WHERE PK.TABLE_NAME = '[Primary Key Table]' and PT.COLUMN_NAME = '[Primary Key Column]';
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to query the sys tables.

The query to get all table names where your column is used as a fk would be something like

```
 select name 
   from sys.tables 
  where object_id in 
       ( select parent_object_id 
           from sys.foreign_key_columns 
          where referenced_object_id = 12345
            and referenced_column_id = 1);
```

To get your referenced_object_id and referenced_column id:

```
select object_id from sys.tables where name = 'Table T'
```

With that object_id, find column id:

```
select column_id from sys.columns where name = 'Column A' and object_id = 12345
```